# C# Get Directory Names

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Here is some code i have been trying to use to get just directory names - However its returning the full filepath rather than all the directories in SUBDIR2.
I can do a split string but the length of the Dir changes

```cs
public void Getdire1(string Servername)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("\\\\" 
        + Servername 
        + "\\E$\\SUBDIR1\\SUBDIR2\\");

    foreach (string item in dirs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(item);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName(string)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=net-5.0

```cs
public void Getdire1(string Servername) 
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("\\\\" + Servername + "\\E$\\SUBDIR1\\SUBDIR2\\");
    

    foreach (string item in dirs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(item));
    }
}
```

See the samples in the docs to make sure you get the desired output, be for example mindful about `C:\mydir` and `C:\mydir\`.

**EDIT:**:

In that case you can use `Path.GetFileName(string)` but this only works if your path does not end with `\`, e.g. `C:\MyDir` works but `C:\MyDir\` won't.

You can use `String.TrimEnd(string)` for this like so:
`"C:\\mydir\\".TrimEnd('\\')`. I think `Path.GetFileName("C:\\mydir\\".TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))` would   work.

Or even this:
`Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\mydir\\"))` but be careful, `C:\DirA\DirB\` will result in `DirB` but `C:\DirA\DirB` will result in `DirA` !

**EDIT2:**
The answer from @Stefano Cavion also seems sensible, although if I just wanted the name I personally would not like to instantiate a whole class just to get the name of a directory from some string. Thats just taste. For funsies i've decided to run a small benchmark to see if there are better choices performance wise, and funnily enough the `.TrimEnd()` solution seems to be the fastest in a way. Of course caring about performance on this level seems a bit too much unless you're doing something very special so take this with a grain of salt...

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.677 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU 2.80GHz (Kaby Lake), 2 CPU, 7 logical and 7 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.202
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UseTrimEnd | 462.2 ns | 17.73 ns | 50.59 ns |
| UseGetDirectoryName | 621.2 ns | 18.26 ns | 53.56 ns |
| UseGetDirectoryInfo | 1,397.8 ns | 26.71 ns | 65.51 ns |

The environment and .net core version would also give some variance, as well as me using the computer whilst the test was running.

Code:

```cs
public class PathBenchMark
{
    public List<string> Paths = new List<string>(new[] { @"C:\MyDir", @"C:\MyDir\", @"C:\A\B", @"C:\A\B\" });

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseTrimEnd() => Paths.Select(c => Path.GetFileName(c.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))).ToList();
    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseGetDirectoryName() => Paths.Select(c => Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(c))).ToList();
    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseGetDirectoryInfo() => Paths.Select(c => new DirectoryInfo(c).Name).ToList();

}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<PathBenchMark>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT3:**
I've ran another benchmark by using `new DirectoryInfo(string).GetDirectories(string)`. I also edited the `UseGetDirectoryName` case, because `Directory.GetDirectories()` returns the full path without trailing `\` which would return the wrong directory... I.e. i'm going with `DirectoryInfo` or with `TrimEnd()` from now on since i don't wanna be making the same mistake.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.677 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU 2.80GHz (Kaby Lake), 2 CPU, 7 logical and 7 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.202
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.14 (CoreCLR 4.700.21.16201, CoreFX 4.700.21.16208), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UseTrimEnd | 49.57 μs | 0.976 μs | 1.085 μs |
| UseGetDirectoryName | 49.30 μs | 0.703 μs | 0.624 μs |
| UseNewDirectoryInfo | 51.82 μs | 1.021 μs | 1.362 μs |
| UseDirectoryInfoGetDirectories | 49.78 μs | 0.789 μs | 0.877 μs |

```cs
public class PathBenchMark
{
    private const string RootPath = @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\";
    public List<string> Paths => Directory.GetDirectories(RootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseTrimEnd() => Paths.Select(c => Path.GetFileName(c.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))).ToList();
    
    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseGetDirectoryName() => Paths.Select(c => Path.EndsInDirectorySeparator(c) ? Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(c)) : Path.GetFileName(c) ).ToList();
    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseNewDirectoryInfo() => Paths.Select(c => new DirectoryInfo(c).Name).ToList();

    [Benchmark]
    public List<string> UseDirectoryInfoGetDirectories() => new DirectoryInfo(RootPath).GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
    
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {        
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<PathBenchMark>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP want only the name of the directory not the path of it so on the example only `mydir`

Comment: I tired the above code and it does return the full file path again - What i do need is what you said @StefanoCavion i just need C:\mydir\ all the SubDirectories of myDir if this makes sense

Comment: @TomDobing if you want take a look to my answer , it use a different class and i think it's way easier than all this string manipulation

Comment: @sommmen just for completition do you mind also do the benchmark using `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` vs `Directory.GetDirectories` (the first should get you all the `DirectoryInfo` already istanziated)

Comment: @StefanoCavion good call, perf seems to be about the same, as long as you don't instantiate a new DirectoryInfo object per subdirectory, that seems to be the slowest.

Comment: @sommmen seems resonable since the under laying calls should be similar., also (this is not our case) `DirectoryInfo` provide a method `EnumerateDirectories` that seems perfmom (at least these is what documentation say) better in case of big quantity of file/directories

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DirectoryInfo` class for retreive all the info you need, take a look to
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0)

```
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("\\\\" + Servername + "\\E$\\SUBDIR1\\SUBDIR2\\");
        foreach(var dir in dirs)
        {
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            MessageBox.Show(dinfo.Name);     //This will show only the directory name
            MessageBox.Show(dinfo.FullName); //This will show the complete path of the directory
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you.

```cs
    public void Getdire1(string Servername)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories("\\\\" + Servername + "\\E$\\SUBDIR1\\SUBDIR2\\");
    
    
        foreach (string item in dirs)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileName(item));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question asks how to retrieve the directory name but not the file name. System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(item)); will be the correct method.

Comment: You should have checked it first. GetFileName( string path) returns the directory name. It simply returns whatever is found after the last '\'. So, if the path contains '\' at the end, it will return an empty string. But in this case the Directory.GetDirectories() returns a path that does not contain the '\' at the end. Therefore, this will return the directory name.